# Colorful prebreak and postbreak tokens with listings package

Tags: listings, color, line-breaking

I want to get colorful `prebreak` and `postbreak` tokens with `listings` package, but the following code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines,prebreak={\space\color{teal}!},postbreak={\color{blue}!\space}]
This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line.
This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines,prebreak={\space\hbox{\textcolor{teal}{!}}},postbreak={\hbox{\textcolor{blue}{!}}\space}]
This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line.
This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is there a need to wrap the `\textcolor` in a `\hbox`, here? Why is this error occurring?

Comment: @Jubobs because if you don't You get an error message from tex telling you to do it:-) Remove the `\hbox` and you get `! Improper discretionary list.`  which is a primitive error in a `\discretionary` texbook says: more precisely, the horizontal list formed by each
discretionary general text must consist only of characters, ligatures,
kerns, boxes, and rules; there should be no glue or penalty items, etc