# listing pre- and postbeak gives error in beamer slide

Tags: beamer, listings

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239400/28926), I've tried to embed a listing with long lines into a beamer frame.

I'd like to have a nice red arrow at the line break (as show [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116572/28926)).

The parameters `prebreak` and `postbreak` give an error while compiling it. As a matter of fact, it's the `\textcolor` that gives the error.

Here is the adapted MWE :

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{%
    xleftmargin=3.4pt,
    xrightmargin=3.4pt,
    %keepspaces=true,
    columns=fullflexible,   % Rasterize the columns
    frame=single,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=\true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
    breaklines=true,
% This works
    postbreak=\mbox{$\hookrightarrow$\space},
% This does not work
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
\begin{lstlisting}
This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line.
This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output of the code, without the `\textcolor` obviously.

[image: MWE output]

If I uncomment the `postbreak` line, I get this error :

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \kern 
l.3 This 
         is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

Any ideas on why does the `textcolor` makes things crash ?

Comment: It is probably a good idea to leave that postbreak line uncommented in the MWE. Then it would fail without the user having to do anything. Here we have to read the MWE to know that it only fails if you remove a `%`

Answer (score 0):

As was already suggested in [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570945/47927) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586477/47927), you should place the arrow inside a box, which will help in the fragile environment:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}

\newsavebox{\mypostbreak}
\savebox{\mypostbreak}{\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}}
\lstset{%
    xleftmargin=3.4pt,
    xrightmargin=3.4pt,
    %keepspaces=true,
    columns=fullflexible,   % Rasterize the columns
    frame=single,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    extendedchars=\true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!10},
    breaklines=true,
% This works
    % postbreak=\mbox{$\hookrightarrow$\space},
% This now also works
    postbreak=\usebox{\mypostbreak},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
\begin{lstlisting}
This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line. This is a long line.
This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line. This is another long line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]