# Missing number, treated as zero within beamer and lstcustom

Tags: listings

I am using the package [lstcustom](https://github.com/markroyer/latex-listings-eclipse), it's a kind of listings.

And I get a confusing error "Missing number, treated as zero".

[image]

I cannot find what I am doing wrong.. :/ Do you have any suggestions?

The resulting pdf looks fine, I guess..

Thank you a lot for your help!

Edit: That's the code from above

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lstcustom}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        
    Die Zahlen können in verschiedener Form dargestellt werden:
            \begin{itemize}         
                \item Dezimalform
                \item Oktalform
\begin{lstlisting}
int i = 011;
System.out.println(i); // 9
\end{lstlisting}


            \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: screenshots are quite useless to debug errors. Learn to make a small, complete example that you can post here.

Comment: Allright, I understand. Edited and added a mwe.

Comment: I cannot compile your MWE as the package `lstcustom` isn't available on my system. Can it be found online? If I replace `\usepackage{lstcustom}` with `\usepackage{listings}`, your test document compiles fine.

Comment: Hey Mico! Take a look above in my post, there is a link to the lstcustom file (on GitHub). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your style uses a color command in the postbreak key. That is rather fragile as the value is used in a discretionary. You can try to replace this with a box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lstcustom}

\begin{document}
\newsavebox\redarrow
\sbox\redarrow{\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}}}
\lstset{postbreak=\usebox\redarrow}

    \begin{frame}[fragile]

    Die Zahlen können in verschiedener Form dargestellt werden:
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Dezimalform
                \item Oktalform
\begin{lstlisting}
int i = 011;
System.out.println(i); // 9
\end{lstlisting}


            \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks a lot!!